# Test Question Experimental Sandbox

Tags: discussion

**Use this as an experimental location to try formatting etc of questions.**

You can place anything you want to try out into an answer to discover if the formatting will function or to simply learn.

Enjoy

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox

Comment: @Chenmunka  each meta site has a sandbox.

Answer (score 3):

### Use this formatting for gifs (because they cannot be uploaded like a regular image):

`<img src="http://example.gif"/>`

(clean copy - `<img src=""/>`)

Example:

[image]

### Use this formatting to resize images, and make them clickable for full size viewing (useful for posts that are long from many large pictures)

`[<img src="https://example.png" height="(number)" />](https://example.png)`

(clean copy - `[<img src="" height="" />]()` )

Example:

[image]

Comment: Do you know how to do the tag reference in a post?

Comment: `[tag:word]` .... @DucatiKiller

Comment: if that's what you meant

Comment: Yes.   Ty.  ;-). It is

Comment: @DucatiKiller also `[meta-tag:word]`

Comment: You can resize imgur uploaded pictures by adding an 's', 'm', or 'l' at the end of the filename before the extension. Something like imageid120931290231**m**.png would render image imageid120931290231.png in medium size.

Answer (score 2):

> **Thanks for your edit!**
> This edit will be visible only to you until it
> is peer reviewed. Just kidding, your edit was horrible, and nobody cared enough to accept it.

Grrr I can't do butterfly text

This is my magic wand:- ้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้

**It's a ball...**http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4f/Soccer_ball_animated.svg **...Kick it.**

<kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd>Wow, this is fun!</kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd>

rè̑ͧ̌aͨl̘̝̙̃ͤ͂̾̆ ZA̡͊͠͝LGΌ ISͮ̂҉̯͈͕̹̘̱ TO͇̹̺ͅƝ̴ȳ̳ TH̘**Ë͖́̉ ͠P̯͍̭O̚​N̐Y̡**

## <sup>M<sub>e</sub></sup><sub>s<sup>s</sup></sub><sup><sub>e</sub>d</sup> up <sup><sub><sup><sub><sup><sub><sup><sub><sup><sub><sup><sub><sup><sub><sup><sub><sup><sub>This is the smallest text you will ever see... there is no way you are reading this unless you viewed the page source or edited my answer or something. This is tiny! Impossibly tiny! Yay! I still haven't filled up a single line with all this text :/ I STILL haven't! Wow! Okay now I filled up a line finally. I will just keep typing okay I don't know what to say.</sub></sup></sub></sup></sub></sup></sub></sup></sub></sup></sub></sup></sub></sup></sub></sup></sub></sup>

*T*`h`**is** i*s* `s`*ome* v**e*r***`y` [od](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/od)<kbd>d</kbd>   <sup>[f](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/f)<kbd>o</kbd></sup><sub>[r](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/r)<kbd>m</kbd></sub><sup>at</sup>ti<sub>ng.</sub>

**Loading, please wait...** http://web.archive.org/web/20120111193542/http://files.quickmediasolutions.com/throbber.svg

## Huh, didn't know this was possible.

rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr

ก็็็็็็็็็็็็็็็็็็็็ กิิิิิิิิิิิิิิิิิิิิ ก้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้ ಠ_ಠ ก็็็็็็็็็็็็็็็็็็็็ กิิิิิิิิิิิิิิิิิิิิ ก้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้

Comment: wow, you're breaking this website

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=activity) is a link to *your* Stack Exchange activity log.

<sup>Practicing writing small...</sup>[image]

Answer (score 1):

[multimeter](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multimeter)
href="https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/3276/mikey">Mikey
72 total votes, 14 question votes, 6 answers, 820 views
[image: Vote Novice (bronze badge): over 30 total upvotes on question and answers] [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question] [image: Pole Position (gold badge): 1st place when sorted by total votes]

[The really really big mountain](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/31250/the-really-really-big-mountain) - [James](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/189/james)
21 total votes, 8 question votes, 3 answers, 149 views
[image: So Close And Yet So Far (silver badge): 2nd place when sorted by total votes]

[What would cause a supermassive plateau that sticks out of the ocean](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/31686/what-would-cause-a-supermassive-plateau-that-sticks-out-of-the-ocean) - [Mikey](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/3276/mikey)
18 total votes, 6 question votes, 5 answers, 112 views
[image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question]

using cisco switches, I am trying to connect the output from ifHCInOctets  to the names of the interfaces via ifName and comparing it to show interfaces counter. I use the last number behind the period to build a relation:

```
IF-MIB::ifHCInOctets.5 -> .5 -> IF-MIB::ifName.5 -> STRING: Gi2/2
```

But the counters don't match.

```
Gi2/2 0 0 0 0

IF-MIB::ifName.5 = STRING: Gi2/2 = Counter64: 316618425031
```

Any ideas what I did wrong? Output Counters:

```
snmpwalk -c XXXXX  -v 2c 11.11.11.11 ifHCInOctets

> IF-MIB::ifHCInOctets.2 = Counter64: 4679059808612
IF-MIB::ifHCInOctets.3 = Counter64: 18081823282428
IF-MIB::ifHCInOctets.4 = Counter64: 889928393035
IF-MIB::ifHCInOctets.5 = Counter64: 316618425031
IF-MIB::ifHCInOctets.6 = Counter64: 317632951365
IF-MIB::ifHCInOctets.7 = Counter64: 236829130669
IF-MIB::ifHCInOctets.8 = Counter64: 64061982573
IF-MIB::ifHCInOctets.9 = Counter64: 0
```

Output interface name:

```
snmpwalk -c XXXXX  -v 2c 11.11.11.11 ifName

IF-MIB::ifName.2 = STRING: Gi1/1
IF-MIB::ifName.3 = STRING: Gi1/2
IF-MIB::ifName.4 = STRING: Gi2/1
IF-MIB::ifName.5 = STRING: Gi2/2
IF-MIB::ifName.6 = STRING: Gi2/3
IF-MIB::ifName.7 = STRING: Gi2/4
IF-MIB::ifName.8 = STRING: Gi2/5
IF-MIB::ifName.9 = STRING: Gi2/6
```

Show interface on the switch (it is the correct switch, checked it :) )

'show interfaces counters

```
`Te1/1 0 0 0 0
Te1/2 10563158165874 15443691040 120647811 290690918
Gi1/3 0 0 0 0
Gi1/4 0 0 0 0
Gi1/5 0 0 0 0
Gi1/6 0 0 0 0
Gi2/1 71889760549 151749380 761995 224509
Gi2/2 0 0 0 0
Gi2/3 10407430146 22164312 316283 168431
Gi2/4 0 0 0 0
Gi2/5 0 0 0 0
Gi2/6 0 0 0 0`
```